# python, featuretools dfs Stream closed error issue

Tags: python-3.x, linux, featuretools

Running featuretools dfs with n_jobs > 1, ***sometimes*** give me(sometimes run without err) `tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed.`

I want to run featuretools dfs n_job >=2 without err in centos linux

full stack error below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mlp-platform/python/component/automl/test/automl_full_test.py", line 113, in <module>
    result1, features = FeatureEvolutionFeatureTools(params=params).run()
  File "/yarn/mlp-platform/python/component/automl/feature_evolution.py", line 42, in run
    trans_primitives=transformer_name, **dfs_init_option)
  File "/yarn/mlp-platform/python/component/automl/feature_evolution.py", line 54, in dfs_wrapper
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x2ba94b588d08>, <Future finished exception=StreamClosedError('Stream is closed',)>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/tcpclient.py", line 232, in connect
    af, addr, stream = yield connector.start(connect_timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/tcpclient.py", line 112, in on_connect_done
    stream = future.result()
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1173, in run
    future_set_exc_info(self.result_future, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 643, in future_set_exc_info
    future.set_exception(exc_info[1])
asyncio.base_futures.InvalidStateError: invalid state    return func(**kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/featuretools/utils/entry_point.py", line 40, in function_wrapper
    raise e
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/featuretools/utils/entry_point.py", line 32, in function_wrapper
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/featuretools/synthesis/dfs.py", line 276, in dfs
    progress_callback=progress_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/featuretools/computational_backends/calculate_feature_matrix.py", line 266, in calculate_feature_matrix
    progress_callback=progress_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/featuretools/computational_backends/calculate_feature_matrix.py", line 534, in parallel_calculate_chunks
    client.replicate([_es, _saved_features])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 3078, in replicate
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 767, in sync
    self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 345, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 329, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

**I figured out below**

1. erase code in featuretools calculate_feature_matrix.py, 595 line

   ```
   if client is not None:
    client.close()
   ```

   no err
2. with n_jobs=1, no err
3. in window, no err

**I'm using**

featuretools 0.13.2

python 3.6.8

Comment: solved by featurelabs

Comment: How did you solve?